# Jquery is not submitting the form with the custom button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

My requirement is to upload a file from a form upon clicking the custom button by using Jquery stuff.

My form details are below:

```
<form id="CreateAttachmentForm" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="../../FileUploadServlet" >
```

My file is defined as below:

```
<input type="file" id="fileupload1" name="fileupload1" accept="image/*,application/pdf"    "/>
```

My custom button related code is below:

```
<contact:contactbutton
        id="printButton"
        style="position:relative; width:90px; top:27px; height:30px; left:160px;"
        textTop="7px"
        defaultButton="false"
        tabindex=""
        accesskey="C"
        onClickEx="createAttachmentRequest();"
        onfocus="if(event.altKey){click();}">
            <u>C</u>reate
</contact:contactbutton>
```

Whenever the user clicks on the custom button, the form should be submitted.I have registered an onClick event event where the control should reach the function named `createAttachmentRequest()`

The following is my `createAttachmentRequest()` function:

```
function createAttachmentRequest() {
    alert("test ");
    $("#CreateAttachmentForm").submit(function() {

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://HDDT0214:8080/pqawdTestWebApp/FileUploadServlet',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data)
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

        return false;
    });


}
```

But the form is not submitted when I click the custom button. I have searched various questions on SO, but no suitable solution found so far.However I could see the alert message printed which confirms that the control is reaching the function `createAttachmentRequest()`.What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I think you are setting the eventlistener for $("#CreateAttachmentForm") when you call $("#CreateAttachmentForm").submit(). You need to do this before the page is loaded. If you want to use the createAttachmentRequest function, you should remove the  $("#CreateAttachmentForm").submit(function() part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're attaching a submit event handler in the function - not actually submitting the form.

It would be best to remove the `createAttachmentRequest()` function entirely and use unobtrusive JS code to attach the event. To do that, remove the `onClickEx` attribute from your `<contact:contactbutton>` element, then use this JS code:

```
$(function() { 
  $("#CreateAttachmentForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://HDDT0214:8080/pqawdTestWebApp/FileUploadServlet',
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData(this),
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
  });
});
```

Also note that I removed `async: false` as it's incredibly bad practice to use it. If you check the console you'll even see warnings about its use.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am just confused. If I remove `onClickEx` attribute from `<contact:contactbutton>` element, then how the click event gets registered? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Clicking the submit button will raise the `submit` event on the form, which is whats being captured through the jQuery `$("#CreateAttachmentForm").submit(fn)` event handler

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing in my question. My `submit` button is hidden field. The user can only click on custom button which in turn submits the form.So there's no way the user can click on `submit` button directly.

Comment: That doesn't matter - the code above hooks to the `submit` event of the form. It doesn't matter how that submit event is triggered. It could be by button click, or by pressing the enter key, or programmatically raised.

Comment: I am sorry to ask you one more question. Could you please let me know where should your code snippet go? Inside createAttachmentRequest() function?

Comment: Anywhere either in the `<head>` *after* you reference jquery.js, or just before `</body>`

Comment: I did put your code inside`<script>` tag. But my custom button is not listening to it. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

Take the submit event outside the function and remove the function like so:

```
$("#CreateAttachmentForm").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://HDDT0214:8080/pqawdTestWebApp/FileUploadServlet',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data)
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
return false;
});
```

**OR**

inside the function remove the submit listener like so:

```
function createAttachmentRequest() {
    alert("test ");
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://HDDT0214:8080/pqawdTestWebApp/FileUploadServlet',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data)
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

        return false;   

}
```